# Making flexbox wrapped items absorb vertical space

Tags: html, css, gridview, flexbox

Im trying to implement a "collage" layout with flexbox where elements of indeterminate heights but fixed width can be "left-floated" in a collage like style (kinda like pintrest) but Im having trouble getting the flex-items to absorb extra VERTICAL space.

**HMTL**

```
<div class="widget-wrap">
    <div class="widget"> <!-- these elements are generated dynamically -->
        <!-- ~ indeterminate amount of content resulting of varying height ~ -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.widget-wrap { 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.widget {
    width: 33.33333%;
    margin-bottom: 0; /* my best guess */
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

As you can see there are vertical gaps whenever one widget is larger than the others in the same row (I guess thats expected using `align-items: flex-start`) but I would like all items in subsequent rows to align themselves flush to item above them in their column like on [pintrest](https://www.pinterest.com/).

Comment: Have you tried adding `align-content: flex-start` ?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll unfortunately have to design your page using 3 columns and putting your content inside these columns.